Python script doesn't run while launched from a shortcut
I have a problem while running a newly created shortcut icon on my Desktop.
I used a Script:
from pyshortcuts import make_shortcut
import os

# Define paths
source_file = r"my_path_to_source_code"
icon_path = r"/home/user/icons/myicon.icns"
shortcut_name = "Find"
desktop_folder = os.path.join(os.path.expanduser("~"), "Desktop")

shortcut_path = make_shortcut(source_file, name=shortcut_name, icon=icon_path)

desktop_shortcut_path = os.path.join(desktop_folder, f"{shortcut_name}.lnk")


The code runs all right, the icon gets created on the desktop but after clicking it the Python command prompt shows up for one second and then instantly closes. I also tried to create a shortcut through Powershell but I've got an Error.

(1) Is the source file path relative or absolute? (2) Can you run the source file from command line?

What is the actual program that the shortcut points to? It is quite possible that the code starts in a command window which closes as soon as the code finishes, or stops due to error.

(1) The source code is in venv (2) Yes I can and everything works fine

If there is an error message, please edit the question and add the error message as text. No pictures.

There is a bunch of likely failure points here. First, if your code is in an env then you probably have to activate that env to get the interpreter and installed modules you want. Secondly, if you are pointing to a .py file then you also need to make sure your shebang is configured correctly. You probably want to point to a shell script that does all the proper preamble for you.

Solution: Long story short, the path to python shortcut was using was not matching the path to venv and some packeges were missing. Creating a shortcut to python in venv and adding an argument pointing to a code i wanted to run solved the problem.

I think the issue you are experiencing is related to the script closing the command prompt window immediately after running. This is a common behavior when running Python scripts directly in a Windows environment.
To keep the command prompt window open after running your script, you can modify the script to use input() to wait for user input before closing the window.
